# Truth value is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
ID      WEEK     TYPE     TYPE_ADJ
1038      1.0      1.0          1.0
1038     13.0      3.0          3.0
1038     26.0      3.0          3.0
1038     38.0      3.0          3.0
1038     52.0      3.0          3.0
1043      1.0      1.0          1.0
1043     13.0      2.0          2.0
1043     26.0      2.0          2.0
1043     38.0      3.0          3.0
1043     52.0      1.0          1.0
```

What I want to do is, when TYPE = 3.0, make TYPE_ADJ the last non 3.0 value of TYPE. I.e. in the data above it would be:

```
ID      WEEK     TYPE     TYPE_ADJ
1038      1.0      1.0          1.0
1038     13.0      3.0          1.0
1038     26.0      3.0          1.0
1038     38.0      3.0          1.0
1038     52.0      3.0          1.0
1043      1.0      1.0          1.0
1043     13.0      2.0          2.0
1043     26.0      2.0          2.0
1043     38.0      3.0          2.0
1043     52.0      1.0          1.0
```

I have tried the following code:

```
for id in df.ID.unique():
    t = [1, 13, 26, 38, 52]
    for n in [0, 1, 2, 3]:
        prior_type = df.loc[(df.ID == id) & (df.WEEK == t[n]), 'TYPE']
        if (df.loc[((df.ID == id) & (df.WEEK == t[n + 1])), 'TYPE'] == 3):
            df.loc[(df.ID == id) & (df.WEEK == t[n + 1]), 'TYPE_ADJ'] = prior_type
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I have tried adding empty, bool, item, any and all and it does not work, and none of the answers on StackOverflow seem to work.

Comment: replace `&` by `and` and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with the following code:

```
df.loc[df["TYPE"] == 3, "TYPE_ADJ"] = None
df["TYPE_ADJ"].ffill(inplace=True)
```

The code removes `TYPE_ADJ`, where `TYPE` equals 3, then forward fills `TYPE_ADJ` with any previous non-missing value.

It takes the last value of `TYPE`, not `TYPE_ADJ`, however in your example they're the same.

Answer (score 1):

The error you get can be avoided by comparing the value of the column rather than the column (Series) itself.

```
if df.loc[(df.ID == id) & (df.WEEK == t[n + 1]), 'TYPE'].values[0] == 3:
```